# Rails collection select of categories and subcategories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to implement the following: I want to put the loop below inside a `select field` and be able to select only the subcategories.

```
@categories = Category.where(ancestry: nil)
@subcategories = Category.where("ancestry is NOT NULL and name != ''")

<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.name %>
      <% unless category.children.empty? %>
        <% category.children.each do |subcategory| %>
          <%= subcategory.name %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the subcategories with this following:

```
<%= form.collection_select(:category_id, @ subcategories, :id, :name) %>
```

But how I can put both the categories(not selectable) and subcategories(selectable) in order inside the select field?

Comment: Look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the right direction @Vasilisa:))))

Comment: Happy that it helped and thank you for adding an answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form.grouped_collection_select :category_id, Category.roots.order(:name), :children, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {class: "", :multiple => true } %>
```